# While using wpf live chart library, I can't show line chart from data. I suspect data binding mistake

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I'm Trying to show a cartesian chart using data from DB.
But I'm stuck at showing data to chart.

I checked the data is correctly put into seriescollection.
So I think there is an error at data binding.

This is my code at xaml file.

```
<wpf:CartesianChart Name="mainChart" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Height="250" Series="{Binding mainData}">
    <wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <wpf:Axis Title="Date" Labels="{Binding mainDataLabel}"></wpf:Axis>
    </wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>
</wpf:CartesianChart>
```

And below is some part of my code related with the chart.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private SeriesCollection mainData;
    private List<string> mainDataLabel;

    public void GetDataAsCondition(SearchCondition condition)
    {

        // Here is some code to get data from DB

        for (int idx = 0; idx < mainDataTable.Columns.Count; idx++)
        {
            if (idx > 0)
            {
                LineSeries tmpLineSeries = new LineSeries();
                List<int> tmpDataList = new List<int>();
                tmpLineSeries.Title = mainDataTable.Columns[idx].ColumnName;

                for (int rowCnt = 0; rowCnt < mainDataTable.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
                {
                    tmpDataList.Add(Int32.Parse(mainDataTable.Rows[rowCnt][idx].ToString()));
                }
                tmpLineSeries.Values = new ChartValues<int>(tmpDataList);

                mainData.Add(tmpLineSeries);

            }
            else if (idx == 0)
            {

                for (int rowCnt = 0; rowCnt < mainDataTable.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
                {
                    mainDataLabel.Add(mainDataTable.Rows[rowCnt][idx].ToString());
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked binding property 'mainData' is declared at mainwindow class.
So I think the binding should work. Where did I make a mistake in this code?
Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to perform the binding to a private field, which is wrong. If you want the binding to work properly mainData and mainDataLabel have to be public properties, instead of fields.

So... It should be:

```cs
public List<string> MainDataLabel { get;set; }

public SeriesCollection MainData { get;set; }
```

I hope it works for you :)

Comment: Thank you Carlos. It worked. Can I ask one more question? when I changed private public, it didn't work. But after I add getter and setter as you directed, it worked. I don,t understand why. Will you give me some information or link of reference of this?

Comment: How can I do that? I'm not used to stack overflow system.

Comment: You just did it buddy!

Comment: That's because the binding system bind to public properties (those who have getter and setter) and not to fields you could try to google a databinding article for more info

Answer (score -1):

You should use Dependency Properties to Binding  Details As Follows:

public static readonly DependencyProperty MainDataLabelProperty = 
         DependencyProperty.Register("MainDataLabel", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow ), new 
            PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSetTextChanged)));

```
  public string MainDataLabel{ 
     get { return (string)GetValue(SetTextProperty); } 
     set { SetValue(MainDataLabelProperty, value); } 
  }
```